# Why ajax loaded content is not showing properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to show products of a particular category when it is clicked by using jquery ajax i.e without reloading the page.

Now when the products load with Ajax it seems that their CSS is disturbed or maybe some jQuery events not loading. I have checked, all the CSS classes are well placed as in original file and also i ave tried the ".on" method as suggested in some other answers but it doesn't do anything. can you please help me find what the problem is?

original look :
[this is what the look should be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFg6N.png)

After Ajax loaded content :
[and this look is after the ajax loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO81A.png)

---

all_products.php (original file)

```
<div  class="product_grid">
          <div class="product_grid_border"></div>

          <div id="prod_container">
          @foreach($products as $product)
          <!-- Product Item -->

            <div class="product_item is_new">
              <div class="product_border"></div>
              <div class="product_image d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center"><img src="{{URL::to('')}}/public/uploads/images/{{$product->image}}" alt=""></div>
              <div class="product_content">
                <div class="product_price">${{$product->price}}</div>
                <div class="product_name"><div><a href="{{URL::to('')}}/user/product/{{$product->id}}" tabindex="0">{{ucwords($product->name)}}</a></div></div>
              </div>
              <div class="product_fav"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></div>
              <ul class="product_marks">
                <li class="product_mark product_discount">-25%</li>
                <li class="product_mark product_new">new</li>
              </ul>
            </div>  


          @endforeach
          </div>


        </div>
```

---

ajax_products.blade.php (to be added via ajax)

```
@foreach($products as $product)
              <!-- Product Item -->

                <div class="product_item is_new">
                  <div class="product_border"></div>
                  <div class="product_image d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center"><img src="{{URL::to('')}}/public/uploads/images/{{$product->image}}" alt=""></div>
                  <div class="product_content">
                    <div class="product_price">${{$product->price}}</div>
                    <div class="product_name"><div><a href="{{URL::to('')}}/user/product/{{$product->id}}" tabindex="0">{{ucwords($product->name)}}</a></div></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="product_fav"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></div>
                  <ul class="product_marks">
                    <li class="product_mark product_discount">-25%</li>
                    <li class="product_mark product_new">new</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>                            
@endforeach
```

---

my_js.js

```
$(document).on('click','.cat',function(){


    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/cart_test/user/get_cats',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { cat : $(this).attr('id')},

      success: function(data){
        d = JSON.parse(data);
        var container = $('#prod_container');
        container.empty();
        container.append(d);        
      },

      error: function()
      {
        alert('error');
      }
    });
});
```

---

frontController.php

```
public function get_cats(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('cat');
    $products = product::where('category_id','=',$id)->get();
    $prods =   view('frontend.modules.ajax_products',compact('products'))->render();

    echo json_encode($prods);
}
```

---

shop.css

```css
.product_grid
{
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
 -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-20px);
 -o-transform: translateX(-20px);
 transform: translateX(-20px);
 width: calc(100% + 40px);
}
.product_grid_border
{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 width: 3px;
 height: 100%;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 z-index: 1;
}
.product_item
{
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
 width: 20%;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 24px;
 text-align: center;
}
.product_border
{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 52px;
 right: 1px;
 width: 1px;
 height: calc(100% - 71px);
 background: #e5e5e5;
}
.product_image
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 115px;
}
.product_image img
{
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 max-width: 100%;
}
.product_content
{
 width: 100%;
}
.product_price
{
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 500;
 margin-top: 25px;
}
.product_item.discount
{
 color: #df3b3b;
}
.product_price span
{
 position: relative;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.product_price span::after
{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 6px;
 left: -2px;
 width: calc(100% + 4px);
 height: 1px;
 background: #8d8d8d;
 content: '';
}
.product_name
{
 margin-top: 4px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.product_name div
{
 width: 100%;
 
}
.product_name div a
{
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #000000;
 white-space: nowrap;
 -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
 -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
 -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
 transition: all 200ms ease;
}
.product_name div a:hover
{
 color: #0e8ce4;
}
.product_fav
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 33px;
 right: 12px;
 width: 36px;
 height: 36px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 border-radius: 50%;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
 -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
 -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
 transition: all 200ms ease;
}
.product_fav:hover
{
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.product_fav i
{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
 -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
 -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 color: #cccccc;
 line-height: 36px;
 pointer-events: none;
 z-index: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
 -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
 -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
 transition: all 200ms ease;
}
.product_fav.active i
{
 color: red;
}
.product_item:hover .product_fav
{
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
}
.product_marks
{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 33px;
 left: 24px;
 -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
 -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
 -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
 transition: all 200ms ease;
}
.product_mark
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 36px;
 height: 36px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 36px;
 font-size: 12px;
}
.product_new
{
 display: none;
 background: #0e8ce4;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
}
.product_discount
{
 display: none;
 background: #df3b3b;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
}
.product_item.is_new .product_new,
.product_item.discount .product_discount
{
 display: inline-block;
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1; 
}
```

shop.js  (this is also not working after ajax)

```js
function initIsotope() {
  var sortingButtons = $('.shop_sorting_button');

  $('.product_grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.product_item',
    getSortData: {
      price: function(itemElement) {
        var priceEle = $(itemElement).find('.product_price').text().replace('$', '');
        return parseFloat(priceEle);
      },
      name: '.product_name div a'
    },
    animationOptions: {
      duration: 750,
      easing: 'linear',
      queue: false
    }
  });

  // Sort based on the value from the sorting_type dropdown
  sortingButtons.each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
      $('.sorting_text').text($(this).text());
      var option = $(this).attr('data-isotope-option');
      option = JSON.parse(option);
      $('.product_grid').isotope(option);
    });
  });

}

/* 

 8. Init Price Slider

 */

function initPriceSlider() {
  if ($("#slider-range").length) {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 1000,
      values: [0, 580],
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
      }
    });

    $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
    $('.ui-slider-handle').on('mouseup', function() {
      $('.product_grid').isotope({
        filter: function() {
          var priceRange = $('#amount').val();
          var priceMin = parseFloat(priceRange.split('-')[0].replace('$', ''));
          var priceMax = parseFloat(priceRange.split('-')[1].replace('$', ''));
          var itemPrice = $(this).find('.product_price').clone().children().remove().end().text().replace('$', '');

          return (itemPrice > priceMin) && (itemPrice < priceMax);
        },
        animationOptions: {
          duration: 750,
          easing: 'linear',
          queue: false
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: if you use inspect element on the container with the category's, does something change when you click it?, as in: does it remove a class, is there other css overruling?

Comment: you suspect *that their CSS is disturbed* - yet you've posed zero CSS. The other very odd thing you're doing is passing HTML using JSON - while this works, since the HTML is just a string, it's still an odd thing to do

Comment: @RamondeVries no i have checked there is no css overruling and it doesn't remove any class in inspector. the thing is if it is displayed before ajax with the same classes correctly, why after ajax it is displaying in a single column given the classes are same.

Comment: @Bravo i will surely correct the JSON thing. i have not attached any css because problem is not with the css definitions . if the same css is working well before ajax then why it is not after ajax (the classes remain same in the ajax loaded content). Maybe the problem is other than css.

Comment: I just think perhaps removing the content from `prod_container` and adding new content may behave oddly depending on the CSS - but if you think it isn't the CSS, then whatever

Comment: @Bravo i have added shop.css and also shop.js (as im working on a template these files were present in the template). shop.js functions are also not working after ajax.